# Determinantal questions on Alternate Sign Matrices

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{A}_n$ be the set of all [Alternating Sign Matrices (ASM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_sign_matrix) of size $n\times n$. The cardinality $\#\mathcal{A}_n$ is [well-known](https://oeis.org/A005130)
$$\#\mathcal{A}_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(3k+1)!}{(n+k)!}.$$

I brought up some questions to bear.

> **QUESTION 1:** What are these values on the sum of determinants?
>   $$\sum_{M\in\mathcal{A}_n}\det(M).$$
>
> **QUESTION 2:** What is known (can be said) about the determinants distribution of these matrices in $\mathcal{A}_n$? Such as, (a) what is the range of possible values? (b) how many are singular/regular? (c) how many achieve the value 1? or -1?

**EXAMPLES.** Define the Laurent polynomial
$$L_n(z)=\sum_{M\in\mathcal{A}_n}z^{\det(M)}.$$
Then, we have $L_2(z)=\frac1z+z$, $L_3(z)=\frac3z + 1+3z$,
$L_4(z)=\frac{12}z+16+ 14z$, 
$$L_5(z)=\frac{86}z + 253  + 90z, \qquad \text{and} \qquad
L_6(z)=\frac2{z^2}+ \frac{1032}z + 5368 + 1032z+ 2z^2.$$
This way, Question 1 reads $L_n'(1)$ where $'=\frac{d}{dz}$.

**Credit.** These computations are made courtesy of Zeilberger's Maple package, [ROBBINS](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/tokhniot/ROBBINS).

Comment: Silly thought, but maybe the $M\in \mathcal{A}_n$ which are not permutation matrices always have determinant zero?

Comment: @SamHopkins $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0&1&0&-1&1\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: A more preposterous question: what is the sum of lambda determinants of all $n\times n$ alternating sign matrices?

Answer (score 3):

(Half of an answer to Question 1)

$M \in \mathcal{A}_n \Leftrightarrow w_0M \in \mathcal{A}_n$, where $w_0 := \mathrm{antidiag}(1,1,...,1)$ (this is just a flip across an axis of symmetry), so when $\binom{n}{2}$ is odd (i.e., $n \equiv 2,3 \mod 4$) we have $\sum_{M \in \mathcal{A}_n} \mathrm{det}(M) = 0$ since in that case $\mathrm{det}(w_0) = -1$, as observed in your data.

Comment: Can we tweak this argument for other values of $n$ by just using a different permutation matrix than the backwards identity? In particular, if we instead let $w_0$ be the identity matrix, except with its left 2 columns swapped, then $\det(w_0) = -1$ regardless of $n$. Furthermore, the rest your argument still seems to work to me, so this should imply that $\sum_{M \in \mathcal{A}_n}\det(M) = 0$ for all $n$, right?

Comment: @NathanielJohnston: Based on T. Amdeberhan's data, it is not true that this sum is 0 for all n.

Comment: Ah of course, my $w_0$ does not preserve alternation of signs. Still should be able to reduce the problem by using other permutations like this I think, but the details are non-trivial.